# Using Contacts in .NET MAUI

Tags: .net, contacts, maui, .net-maui

the .NET MAUI documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/contacts?tabs=android) shows this:

`var contact = await Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Communication.Contacts.PickContactAsync();`

however, when I use it, contact always comes back null. Has something changed or am I missing something?

Comment: have you added the required permission?

Comment: Yes, in the manifest. Thanks.

Comment: did that work or are you still having issues with it?

Comment: For Android platform, you can simply using `var  contact = await Contacts.Default.PickContactAsync();`. I tested it on the real android device, it can get the conatct as expected.

Comment: Will have to try a device. With the emulator it still comes back null. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure there are contacts in your device or emulator. When calling the method `Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Communication.Contacts.PickContactAsync();`, it'll require you to choose the existing contact, otherwise, it'll return `NULL`.

For `Android`, it can be simplified as code below:

```
var contact = await Contacts.Default.PickContactAsync();
```

For `iOS` and `Windows`, you can use the code below:

```
var contact = await Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Communication.Contacts.PickContactAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using exactly that code, and have set the permissions. I wonder if this is a bug in .NET MAUI. I just upgraded VS to Preview 4 so I'll try that again. Thanks again. -jesse

Answer (score 0):

I've duplicated this as the emulator always returning null.  Try an actual device, which is working fine for me.